# How to Get Embed URLs for AWS Quicksight Dashboards using Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, aws-java-sdk, amazon-quicksight

I think I understand all the steps necessary to get the embed URL for an AWS Quicksight dashboard, and I have been able to get a valid URL via the AWS CLI as described in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-with-iam-setup-step-3.html).

However, I can't seem to get it to work via the AWS Java SDK (specifically v2).  There doesn't seem to be a good example anywhere.

Does anyone know of a good working example using Java (or Groovy) preferably using Spring Boot (or Grails 3 or 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here's a working [Groovy/Grails sample project](https://github.com/tonyerskine/aws-sdk-java-v2-quicksight-embed-example) that gets Quicksight dashboard URLs using the AWS Java SDK v2.

**Summary**

I followed a modified version of the process outline in the AWS docs, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-with-iam-setup-step-3.html).  The docs say to have your service account assume the user's IAM role and then request the dashboard as the end user using `IdentityType.IAM`.  However, I made the request to get the url as the service account, without assuming the user's role, and specified the end user's ARN and `IdentityType.QUICKSIGHT` in the API call.

**Code** ([full code](https://github.com/tonyerskine/aws-sdk-java-v2-quicksight-embed-example/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails4test/ApplicationController.groovy))

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.quicksight.QuickSightClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.quicksight.model.*

class ApplicationController {
    String roleName = "embed-dashboard"
    String namespace = "default"
    String awsAccountId
    String dashboardId
    QuickSightClient quickSightClient

    def index(String awsAccountId, String email, String dashboardId) {

        //unimportant code removed

        String url = fetchEmbedUrl(email)
        render "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>Dashboard</a>"
    }

    private String fetchEmbedUrl(String email) {
        // look up the user by email address
        // if we don't find the user register them
        User user = fetchUser(email) ?: registerUser(email)

        // get the dashboard URL
        String embedUrl = quickSightClient.getDashboardEmbedUrl(GetDashboardEmbedUrlRequest.builder()
            .awsAccountId(awsAccountId)
            .dashboardId(dashboardId)
            .userArn(user.arn)
            .identityType(IdentityType.QUICKSIGHT)
            .sessionLifetimeInMinutes(600L)
            .build()
        ).embedUrl

        log.info("URL:\n$embedUrl")

        return embedUrl
    }

    private User fetchUser(String email) {
        return quickSightClient.listUsers(ListUsersRequest.builder()
            .awsAccountId(awsAccountId)
            .namespace(namespace)
            .build()
        ).userList().find { it.email() == email }
    }

    private User registerUser(String email) {
        String roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::$awsAccountId:role/$roleName"
        return quickSightClient.registerUser(RegisterUserRequest.builder()
            .awsAccountId(awsAccountId)
            .namespace(namespace)
            .identityType(IdentityType.IAM)
            .iamArn(roleArn)
            .userRole("READER")
            .email(email)
            .sessionName(email)
            .build()
        ).user()
    }

}
```